# Nunjucks if statement

Tags: nunjucks

I am currently investigating if we can make a query string var work within a nunjucks if statement

The below hardcoded value works "5" and brings back the expected result:

```
{% block content %}
{% for client in clients %}    
{% if client.id == 5 %}

{{client.client}}

{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

I have the current page id from the url stored in a variable but i can't seem to replace "5" with the actual var

Is this possible?

Edit added JQuery

`$(document).ready(function () {
 $.urlParam = function (name) {
        var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
        return results[1] || 0;
    }
    var newid = $.urlParam('id');
   alert(newid);
});`

Thanks a lot of any time spent.
TCP

Comment: `{% if client.id == current_id %}`?

Comment: What is the connection between the nunjucks snippet and the jQuery snippet you've shown? 

Nunjucks will not have any access to variables unless they're available when you compile the template.